# Is this homebrew sword balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, homebrew

I liked the idea of a magical weapon that affected the stats of creatures. Such as the shadow's strength drain attack and added it too a weapon.

**Leech sword** (Very rare, Heavy, two handed, strength weapon)

2 charges (Resets after a long rest) As a bonus action you can use a charge to steal the Strength score of an enemy (1D4) on a successful hit. Your sword steals this Strength and adds it to the damage of the attack, for the next 10 minutes.

1D8+2 +Strength stolen

If you roll a nat 1 the sword steals 1D4 of your own Strength, which you'll regain after a long rest.

Comment: What does "strength" mean in the context of this weapon? Does it refer to the Strength score of the target?

Comment: The strength score I should have clarified in the post mb.

Comment: Alright, so this weapon takes away 1d4 from the target's Strength score and adds that number to the damage roll. Interesting concept. You must specify what type of sword it is. Is it a longsword, greatsword, shortsword, rapier, or even a scimitar? Also, weapon properties such as Heavy are only applied to that type of weapon. For example, a magic shortsword cannot have the Heavy property, as it does not appear on a normal shortsword. Aside from those things, great concept.

Comment: I think you've got a cool concept here, but it doesn't seem like you've fully fleshed it out for us to review. We've got some [guidelines](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121) to help you through the homebrew and review process, but the biggest is seeing your own self review and highlight anything specific you think should have extra attention.

Comment: How can the stolen strength be healed? As far as I recall, every other ability that lowers ability scores in 5e tells us how is this healed. Also, what is supposed to happen when this is used on one target twice? What happens when STR goes to 0? This should be in the item description - if there are general rules, ability damage is so rare that this item should point to them, not expect players to remember where they are.

Comment: To build on NotArch's comment, discussion on what other items from the DMG or other sources that you looked at to form the basis for this proposed item is a big help.

Comment: You have a good start for an interesting weapon here! I'm looking forward to some more details.